# Hide item in ActionBar in Activity with Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

**Requirements** - I have an app with 3 fragments wrapped in ViewPager. There is a Toolbar in Activity, which has 2 menu items and I want to show one of them only when the 2nd fragment is selected.

**Problem** - My code throws NullPointerException

Stacktrace:

```
11-27 15:10:01.940 25899-25899/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 15:10:01.940 25899-25899/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.michael.ims_application_apps.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:67)
11-27 15:10:01.940 25899-25899/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
11-27 15:10:01.940 25899-25899/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:262)
11-27 15:10:01.940 25899-25899/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
11-27 15:10:01.
```

And this is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ViewPager pager;
    private AdapterFragment mAdapter;
    private PageIndicator mIndicator;
    private String name;
    MyTimer tim;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar myToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        // Pada activity ini akan make AdapterFragment
        mAdapter = new AdapterFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Untuk ViewPagerIndicator
        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // TitlePageIndicator merupakan class di library ViewPagerIndicator
        mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

        if(pager.getCurrentItem() != 1)
        {
            MenuItem sync = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_sync);
            sync.setVisible(false);
        }

        //Hidupin session waktu N.B: Waktu boleh berapa lama apps ke-pause secara pastinya belum diset !!!!
//        tim = new MyTimer(50000,10);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();



        // set OptionButton yang di device
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.action_sync:
                if(pager.getCurrentItem() != 1)
                {
                    Log.d("Tag", pager.getCurrentItem()+"");
                    setVisible(false);
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sync", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.Logout:
                SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("USER", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                editor.putString("userName", "-1");
                editor.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override activity's `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and put the hiding/showing logic there.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sync);
  item.setVisible(pager.getCurrentItem() == 1);
  return true;
}
```

Then call activity's `invalidateOptionsMenu()` each time different fragment shows up ([see ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)). It will trigger `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: It still not work, mate

this is my code

@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        if(pager.getCurrentItem() != 1)
        {
            MenuItem sync = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_sync);
            sync.setVisible(false);
        }
        return  true;
    }

Did I miss something?

Comment: Almost there. `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sync);`

Comment: Yes, it works, mate, but the next problem, after 2nd fragment selected, and I move to 3rd fragment, that item still show up, but in first, it gone

Comment: instead of the if-statement write it this way: https://gist.github.com/RobertoArtiles/b5844617fa1e53885348

Comment: Ah, really good idea, mate. But sometime it show in not 2nd fragment, mate, maybe that is a bug?
This is a message : 11-27 16:21:15.980 16311-16311/com.example.michael.ims_application_apps A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000b7f (code=0), thread 16311 (pplication_apps)

Comment: Fo you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on every `onPageSelected()`?

Comment: Like this https://gist.github.com/RobertoArtiles/b5844617fa1e53885348#file-onpagechangelistener-java  Right?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I placed it in wrong place, Mate. Thank you very much for your help. I really glad for your help, Mate

Comment: Hi, what if I wanted to access activity's menu items from the fragment? Not from the activity itself. Thank you..